# While checking for Fingerprint authentication available in device getting security exception with suggestion to add permission INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api, android-securityexception

While we're checking whether Android device has fingerprint authentication available with the following code

```
fun isFingerprintAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
    val fingerprintManager: FingerprintManagerCompat = FingerprintManagerCompat.from(context)
    return fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()
}
```

we're facing a crash issue in Android 6.0.1 Samasung Galaxy J Pop device (in all other devices it is working fine) with following error details:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException
Permission Denial: getCurrentUser() from pid=4722, uid=10162 requires 
android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
com.utils.biometric.BiometricUtils.isFingerprintAvailable
```

Is this something related to biometric functionality? Why is this permission required and if we go on to add this, will we have to request it at runtime as well?

Kindly help with the detailed responses.

Comment: have you added permission to your manifest?

Comment: That permission shouldn't be necessary to add. I've seen this problem on a Galaxy S7, the first time I called `hasEnrolledFingerprint` after a reboot. It would go away if I called `isHardwareDetected` before calling `hasEnrolledFingerprint`.

Comment: @Michael Does that mean this issue is happening because the device doesn't support fingerprint hardware at all?

Comment: I don't know anything about the Galaxy J Pop. But in the case of the Galaxy S7, it _does_ have fingerprint support. So the exception seemed to be the result of some bug in Samsung's software, and making sure to call `isHardwareDetected` before `hasEnrolledFingerprints` was a workaround to avoid getting that exception.